# Xcode Consequences of Raising Minimum Deployment Target for Users of older OS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, app-store

Say I raise the minimum deployment target to iOS 15 for a new version release when it was iOS 14 before. Will users on iOS 14 still be able to download the old version with the lower deployment target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes.
Your old version will still be available.

Comment: it means if new users want to download app can do it with related deployment target?